# What kind of information can be obtained from a digital image

Tags: image, image-processing, information-extraction

I have seen in picasa that we can find the details of camera and date at which an image is taken. I want to know what kind of other information's can be find out using a digital image. Do you know any tools which can be used for this purpose?

Comment: You're looking for an EXIF-viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXIF Tags contain additional information about the image:
[Wikipedia "Exchangeable image file format"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format)

It really depends on the image and camera the image was taken with, but the most common fields include: Date, Manufacturer, Model, Orientation, Compression, Flash info, GPS-Info (newer/better cameras) and much more.

There are various tools for reading EXIF data:
- The simplest of all may be the Windows Explorer itself (Right click on the image and you can read all EXIF Tags)
- More sophisticated programs like the Adobe Suite can also be used to read EXIF Data.

Comment: As @ninetwozero already pointed out, a popular command line utility for this purpose would be [EXIFutils](http://www.hugsan.com/EXIFutils/)